# Is it possible to select fields in included model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to retrieve a `Person` (`self`) and his `history` all at once.
`History` have many field, so I want to retrieve only some columns, how can I achieve that?

```
where_clause = "1=1" # irrelevent query

self.where(reference: 12345)
    .includes(:history)
      # .select(:history_name, :history_key)
      .where(where_clause)
      .references(:history)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you are using `includes` to eager load records but which is not required here because you are directly selecting values. An `select` clause not work with `includes` you can use `joins` as

```
Person.joins(:history).select(:history_name, :history_key).where(where_clause)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use them like this

```
self.where(reference: 12345)
  .includes(:history)
  .select(history: { :history_name, :history_key })
  .where(where_clause)
  .references(:history)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select('history.field_name1',  'history.field_name2')
```